# i want to use the to_daytime function on a column made of a tuple (string)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a  Pandas DataFrame containing a column named "weekday" containing dates as strings.
This is how i merged them, they were all int64 before i transformed them to str.

```
usaClean["weekday"]= usaClean["day"].astype(str) + "/" + usaClean["month"].astype(str) + "/" + usaClean["day"].astype(str) + "/" + usaClean["year"].astype(str) #merge 3 columns into one column while changing to str type
usaClean.head() #the slash (/) does not get accepted with int, it works with str type
```

The result is this : 1988/12/31 . when i use the funtcion like this :

```
usaClean["weekday"]=pd.to_datetime(usaClean["weekday"],dayfirst=True)
usaClean["weekday"]=usaClean.weekday.dt.weekday
```

it shows this error :

> ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: why doing `dayfirst=True` ?

Comment: i fixed the parameters to this : usaClean["weekday"]=pd.to_datetime(usaClean["weekday"], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d', exact=True)